# Optimize macOS Finder for VPN connections that aren't the fastest?

Tags: mac, vpn, finder

Is there a way to optimize the macOS Finder for VPN connections that aren't the fastest?

What I mean is, that finder always tries to load more or less "unnecessary" stuff which I don't need if I just want to download a file.

The navigation in folders is fast and responsive, but when I get in the last folder where files are located in, Finder wants to download previews of those files, and that takes ages. And until this is finished, finder won't even respond correctly and I have to wait.

Is there a "lightweight mode" without previews or anything like this? When I connect with Windows, the explorer is super fast and I can navigate to my files and download them.

Yes, the download is still slow and depends on the connection, but at least something has started and I can do other things instead of waiting for finder to respond to even select the correct file and download it.

I use SMB for Windows and Mac, the connection is the same. So Finder is the issue here I assume.

Based on Tetsujins answer:
This is how my windows looks like:
[image: Cmd J Window]

Comment: A workaround could be to open a terminal window in the folder before the one with the files and then cd into the folder with the files, ls to list them, and cp to copy one to your computer. [How can I open a Terminal window directly from my current Finder location?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location) might still work.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tested this over a VPN, but the result should be the same either way.

Disable icon previews…
Choose your folder, hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  [or View Menu > Show View Options]then uncheck 'Show icon preview' - uncheck relative dates & Calculate all sizes too, they're both slow.

Also, optionally set this as default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Where did you get this advanced options? I don't have the whole part about sizes and "data" - create - last  modified. Where can I enable advanced options? I've added a screenshot of my window. It's in german, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Use List View [Cmd/2] not Column [Cmd/3]. Those options just don't exist in Column view.